# Can't figure out how to write an integer to a file with write()

Tags: c, file, arguments

I'm trying to write the size of the file members[count] (members is an array of char* that holds file names) into a file. I googled it to see what other people have done and this is what I found but nothing is getting written to the file when I open it.

```
int file_len;
file_len = strlen(basename(members[count]));
write(file_desc, &file_len, sizeof(int));
```

If I originally tried the following:

```
int file_len;
file_len = strlen(basename(members[count]));
write(file_desc, ("%d", file_len), sizeof(int));
```

But I get this compiler error:

"passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"

I did something similar in a different part of the program and it worked fine but there's something about it being an integer that's making it not work

Comment: The first sentence should say "I'm trying to write the size of the fileNAME members[count] (members is an array of char* that holds file names) into a file."

Answer (score 0):

Using `write()` for writing integers can be tricky, because it will handle the integer in its binary form. If `file_len` happens to be zero, it will actually write only the null byte `(0x0)`

If you don't want to get too messy, use [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), like this:

```
FILE * file_desc = fopen("yourfile.txt", "w");
/* your code here */
fprintf(file_desc, "%d", file_len);
```

Comment: For some reason my professor is requiring us to use write() for all file input